# General error : '"mysqldump"' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: php, laravel, database-backups

I use Laravel Spatie Backup, the installation is complete,
first running this `$ composer require spatie/laravel-backup`

```
$ composer require spatie/laravel-backup

Using version ^5.6 for spatie/laravel-backup
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 3 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing spatie/temporary-directory (1.1.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing spatie/db-dumper (2.9.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing spatie/laravel-backup (5.6.0): Downloading (100%)
spatie/laravel-backup suggests installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (Allows notifications to be sent via Slack)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
```

and then $ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Backup\BackupServiceProvider"

```
 $ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Backup\BackupServiceProvider"

Copied File [\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\config\backup.php] To [\config\backup.php]
Copied Directory [\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\resources\lang] To [\resources\lang\vendor\backup]
Publishing complete.
```

But when I run

```
php artisan backup:run
```

this error appear

> Backup failed because: The dump process failed with exitcode 1 :
>   General error : '"mysqldump"' is not recognized as an intern al or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

**NOTE**: I use Laravel version 5.6
and Spatie v.5

Comment: If you type `mysqldump` on your server, what is the output? Also what operating system (and version) are you operating on?

Comment: In your `config/database.php` file, edit the mysql database config and add:

`'dump_command_path' =>' '` // absolute path to where mysqldump lives on your system That path is probably this, or something very similar:  `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `config/database.php` file, edit the mysql database config and add:

```
'dump_command_path' =>' '
```

Which is the absolute path to where mysqldump lives on your system That path is probably this, or something very similar:  `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`

Comment: Actually I do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49788342/9246297 but it is helps me!

Comment: another question i have is when i run php artisan:backup everything works but when i run the backup command from the button thats generated by the package , nothing works

Answer (score 21):

In your `config/database.php` file, edit the mysql database config and add:

```
'dump' => [
   'dump_binary_path' => 'C:/xampp/mysql/bin/', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
   'use_single_transaction',
   'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
],
```

Comment: how about, if I used sql server ?

Answer (score 10):

I face this issue

please follow this
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v4/installation-and-setup#dumping-the-database

```
//config/database.php
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql'
        ...,
        'dump' => [
                'dump_binary_path' => 'D:/xampp/mysql/bin/', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
                'use_single_transaction',
                'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
            ], 
    ],
```

Answer (score 4):

It'll fix your problem by adding this line to your config/database file for taking backup of files and database. It will work 100%.

Here is the Image to show where you have made changes.
[image]

Comment: this works. thank you or the clarification